# Vue.js update parent data with an input from a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 2 and I'm trying to update the description of a file using an input in a child component. I've been reading a few related questions and read some of the [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) along with *.sync* but I'm struggling to get the result I want since *files* is a list of objects.

Here's what I've been trying.

```js
Vue.component('myComponent', {
  props: ["file"],
  data() {
    return {
      myDescription: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myDescription = this.file.description;
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <label>{{ file.name }}</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" @input="update" :value="myDescription"></input>
        <br><br>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$emit("update-description", this.myDescription, this.file);
    },
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    updateDescription(description, file) {
      console.log(description);
    }
  },
  data: {
    files: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Hello",
        description: "",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "World",
        description: "Foo",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "John",
        description: "Bar",
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div> {{ files }} </div>
  <br>
  <my-component v-for="file in files" :key="file.id" :file="file" @update-description="updateDescription" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you can see in the code you've provided that the child component event is being emitted but the value is empty. The problem is you're not updating `myDescription`, if you change your `:value` to `v-model` then it will update, as `v-model` uses two way binding.

Also, if you want to update the file description, you can just do:

```
file.description = description;
```

```js
Vue.component('myComponent', {
  props: ["file"],
  data() {
    return {
      myDescription: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myDescription = this.file.description;
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <label>{{ file.name }}</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" @input="update" v-model="myDescription"></input>
        <br><br>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$emit("update-description", this.myDescription, this.file);
    },
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    updateDescription(description, file) {
      console.log(description);
      file.description = description;
    }
  },
  data: {
    files: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Hello",
        description: "",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "World",
        description: "Foo",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "John",
        description: "Bar",
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div> {{ files }} </div>
  <br>
  <my-component v-for="file in files" :key="file.id" :file="file" @update-description="updateDescription" />
</div>
```